# JSONB Type -split in multiple columns

Tags: python, json, pandas, jsonb

I have a jsonb column that came from database and  i want to split this Column and create separate columns for the Values,Field,Timestamp. My current dataframe is :

| Id | Fields" |
| --- | --- |
| 1009331137 | {"101011182899": {"Value": "12.3", "Timestamp": "2021-01-08"}, "101011402899": {"Value": "34.2", "Timestamp": "2021-01-08"}} |

This is the desired output :

| Id | Field | Value | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1009331137 | 101011182899 | 12.3 | 2021-01-08 |
| 1009331137 | 101011402899 | 34.2 | 2021-01-08 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can slightly change the structure of the dictionary to get the output we want. So let's convert nested dictionary to flattened dictionary.

```
df["Fields"] = df["Fields"].apply(lambda x: [{"Field":k,**v} for k,v in x.items()])
```

**New format**:

```
    id          Fields
0   1009331137  [{'Field': '101011182899', 'Value': '12.3', 'Timestamp': '2021-01-08'}, {'Field': '101011402899', 'Value': '34.2', 'Timestamp': '2021-01-08'}]
```

Now we can use **[`explode()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html)** and **[`json_normalize()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html)**

```
df = df.explode("Fields").reset_index(drop=True)
df = df.join(pd.json_normalize(df.pop("Fields")))
```

**Out**:

```
           id         Field Value   Timestamp
0  1009331137  101011182899  12.3  2021-01-08
1  1009331137  101011402899  34.2  2021-01-08
```